# Should I check VisualElement.IsVisible before setting it?

Tags: c#, optimization, xamarin.forms

Visual elements in Xamarin Forms are made visible/invisible by setting their IsVisible property. Changing some properties or data on visual elements can cause the interface to redraw, which can be expensive.

I'm trying to improve performance on my app so I've introduced caching and tried to make some layout simplifications, but I have to make a lot of visual elements visible/invisible and wondered wht the best way would be to optimise this.

Which is the more efficient operation?

```
var myButton.IsVisible = true;
```

Or:

```
if(!myButton.IsVisible) myButton.IsVisible = true;
```

If Xamarin already checks the state and decides whether to redraw then the second option is redundant and  therefore inefficient. If a redraw happens every time the property is set then it will be more efficient. I can't find any documentation to tell me which is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* good implementation of a `DependencyProperty` (or `INotifyPropertyChanged`) member should ignore successive `set`s if that `value` is the same.  For that reason let `IsVisible` work out what to do rather than place responsiblity on callers.

> If Xamarin already checks the state and decides whether to redraw then the second option is redundant and therefore inefficien

That's right. Xamarin, like other XAML-based implemenations, are *visually-efficient* (unlike WinForms) so setting a visual property is not likely to immediately cause a screen refresh.  Additonally, the entire app window is rendered in a single blit to avoid flicker.

In Xamarin, setting `button.IsVisible` for example makes it way down to [`BindableObject.SetValueActual`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs) (`Button` has `BindableObject` in its inheritance graph) where checks are made for sameness.  The new value is only applied if the value is different or if `SetValueFlags.RaiseOnEqual` is set.

`OnPropertyChanged` and `PropertyChanged` are called on different values or if `RaiseOnEqual` is set.

**Xamarin source code** from [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs):  (my comments)

```
void SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, object value, bool currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, bool silent = false)
{
    object original = context.Value;
    bool raiseOnEqual = (attributes & SetValueFlags.RaiseOnEqual) != 0;
    bool clearDynamicResources = (attributes & SetValueFlags.ClearDynamicResource) != 0;
    bool clearOneWayBindings = (attributes & SetValueFlags.ClearOneWayBindings) != 0;
    bool clearTwoWayBindings = (attributes & SetValueFlags.ClearTwoWayBindings) != 0;

    bool same = ReferenceEquals(context.Property, BindingContextProperty) ? ReferenceEquals(value, original) : Equals(value, original);
    if (!silent && (!same || raiseOnEqual))
    {
        property.PropertyChanging?.Invoke(this, original, value);

        OnPropertyChanging(property.PropertyName);
    }

    if (!same || raiseOnEqual)
    {
        context.Value = value; // <---------- assignment
    }
.
.
.
    if (!silent && (!same || raiseOnEqual)) // <------- notifications guard
    {
        if (binding != null && !currentlyApplying)
        {
            _applying = true;
            binding.Apply(true);
            _applying = false;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(property.PropertyName);

        property.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, original, value);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, you can check the `PropertyChanged` implementation that Xamarin is using to verify that this is correct: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs

Comment: @MihailDuchev confirmed good sir. Please see update